# ATL/COM: MIDL compiler doesn't output UUID for dispinterface

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, com, atl

While implementing a connection point for events fired from my class, I declared a `dispinterface` in my IDL like so

```
[
  uuid(123-MY-GENERATED-GUID)
]
dispinterface _IMyChangeEvents {
properties:
methods:
  [id(1)] void ItemChanged([in] BSTR changeInformation);
};
```

According to several sources, including the book "ATL Internals", this should produce a `DIID__IMyChangeEvents` which I can then use to derive my class from `ATL::IConnectionPointImpl<ImplClass, IID>`. But neither is it there nor can I use  `__uuidof(_IMyChangeEvents)` in the `CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY` macro as described in the documentation because it complains "No GUID has been associated with this object".

What's the correct way to implement this?

Comment: The code snippet looks good, the problem is somewhere else: IDL is not compiled, you don't include C++ files generated out of IDL etc.

Comment: I tried deleting the generated header and it is regenerated when I build the project. But it will only include a forward declaration and neither MIDL_INTERFACE nor DECLSPEC_UUID. Also other interfaces from the file are found just fine, the complaint about a missing GUID for this interface is the only error that's left.

Comment: Because the short code snippet above looks good, you make us guessing where the actual problem is. You might want to look at samples online, or my [VbsEvents](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents/) for example. You will see that [`_IFooEvents`](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents/VbsEvents.idl#L31) then generates UUID-enabled `DIID__IFooEvents` on the [`VbsEvents_i.c`](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/VbsEvents/VbsEvents_i.c#L76), which is then included by C++ code, in particular via `__uuidof(...)`.

Comment: I now found this link which confused me some more: http://microsoft.public.vc.language.narkive.com/JqCwWfLp/idispatch-and-dispinterface.2 which, although a bit dated, suggests that the shown behaviour is correct and I'm missing something. But if you say that everything is correct like this, I'll try with some wizard-generated code in another project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this code snippet inside or outside the library{} block? Everything outside library{} goes into the generated .h file. Everything defined or referenced inside library{} goes into the generated .tlb file.

A typical .IDL file would look something like this:

```
interface IMyMainInterface {...};
dispinterface MyEvents {...};

library {
  coclass MyCoClass {
    [default] IMyMainInterface;
    [default, source] MyEvents;
  }
}
```

This way, you would have everything both in .h and in .tlb, for your clients' convenience.

Comment: Interestingly, I also successfully tried it the other way 'round: have the dispinterface in the `library {}` block and a coclass emitting the events outside. Thanks for the explanation on the generation process, I think I understand it better now.